# Ice-Rock Spell Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, scripting, animation-nodes, splines

I'm trying to get effect below in Animation Nodes.

The effect seems simple enough, I just don't know how to set it up. Anyway thanks for looking.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Construct a small block of circular matrices to place stones.
[image]

Evaluate spline to get points on the path. Using loop we can scatter small block to these points.
[image]

Now randomly place stones from the collection to these matrices.
[image]

Add fade falloff with interpolation to control scale. you can also add delay falloff to animate increasing scale.
[image]

[image]